# How can I prevent Internet Explorer from repeat displaying the same background image in every page of a print out using a print CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, printing, styles

Here's a description of the problem: for starters, I have a background logo image displaying on the webpage version (`screen` media) at the top of the page spanning the entire width of the page (basically a masthead).

Then I added a print stylesheet and have been hiding and showing certain parts to optimize the experience for users and their printers .

However, and here's the problem, I noticed that on IE in every page of the print preview the logo image is being added to the top of every page in the print out when the page content is enough for more than one page in the total number of pages. So if there's enough content for 3 pages then in all those three pages the logo image appears at the top every page in the print out, when it should only appear in the 1st one.

I've checked my CSS and I can't find whats going on. I don't have the section that contains the CSS class that defines the background image repeated more than once. This only happens on IE. Not on Chrome nor Firefox.

Here's an excerpt of the HTML:

```
    ....
    <body>
        <div class="repeating-bg-img">
            <div class="container">
            ...
            <!-- /.inner content that is long enough for more than one page -->

            ...
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.repeating-bg-img -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's an excerpt of the CSS in the `print.css` stylesheet with media = `print` :

```
.repeating-bg-img {
    background: #ffffff url('../img/background-image.png') scroll repeat-x left top;
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before on IE? If so, do you have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. One solution is a structure like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="background" style="position: relative;">
  <img src="bkgnd.png" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;">
    <div class="container" ...>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The basic idea is to take the image out of the flow but position it relative to its containing <div>. The z-index pushes it behind other elements. So this can be used as any kind of column header.

One upside to this is that the background image will print even if the "background images" option isn't set in the print dialog. I'd like to see a proper solution as well though.

*Edit 2013/07/23*:

It looks like the CSS3 property will be `box-decoration-break`. This isn't going to help with older versions of IE but the spec is available here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-decoration-break

If what you really want is a masthead, I also thought this might work:

```
@media print {
  div#background { background: none; }
  @page  :first  { background: url('bkgnd.png') center no-repeat;
                 margin: ...; }
}
```

But it looks like that is CSS3 as well. Chrome loads the image from the server but only honors the 'margin' attribute; Firefox and IE9 seem to ignore all of it.